# Understanding Google Cloud Service Account Logs - What should I expect to see?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging

I have few questions related to GCP logging.

Activity Logs: Currently, when I inspect the logs for a specific service account, I can only see entries related to its creation. Shouldn't I be able to see all activity related to this service account, or is it typical to only see specific events?

Impersonation: If another service or user impersonates the service account, is this event recorded in the logs? If so, what should I look for to identify such events?

Interactions via Credentials: If an external application or service interacts with Google Cloud using the credentials of the service account, would this produce a log entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activity logs log all the system change events that you have on your scope. They are kept 400 days in case of investigation. The scope is the perimeter of the action of the service account. If it performs an action on a project, the activity logs will appear in that project (and not in the project which host (and created) the service account identity). Similarly, if the service account performs action on the organization or a folder, you can see that logs at this level.

---

When you impersonate a service account and use this impersonated credential to perform operation, you will see as principal, the service account email. However, you can keep track of the impersonation chain by looking into the serviceAccountDelegationInfo block

---

Using a built in credential service (also named [metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/overview), all the Google Cloud Services has a metadata server that load automatically the Service Account credential without external keys. It's a bad practice to have keys and you have to use them in very limited use cases.) or using a service account key generates the same type of logs. You will see the credential email in the logs (in the principal block). Some API also logs the HTTP user agent and/or the source IP. Not the case for all the APIs (AFAIK!)

---

More details [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/audit-logging/examples-service-accounts)

Comment: Thanks for detailed info, I'll go through this.